# What is the right way for the html form input fields validations

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I am wondering about the form fields validation. I have been doing validations through client side scripting like JavaScript and also with PHP. If a user turns off JavaScript, the client side validation would not work of-course. Then why we go for both server and client side validations. I mean isn't server side validation is enough instead of using client side validation too.

What i believe is, regular expressions are used to filter the garbage or invalid data format that a user can enter accidentally or by his choice. For example, input field for an email address but user entered 1233456 instead. So, its a garbage. Before interacting with database, the data should be validated.

Can i do these sort of validations inside a controller using Model View Controller design pattern, before interacting with database. Will it be a good practice.?

Please make guide me and make me correct if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Client side validation is and should be treated as a nice to have. It's a way to inform the user he/she screwed something up *before* making a request to the server.

Comment: Not all web users turn off JS of their browsers, only the advance users like hackers attempt that to get into your system and do bad things. Client side validation provides easy and quick response to almost 90% of your site users. So its better to do both JS and server side validations.

Comment: "only the advance users like hackers attempt that to get into your system and do bad things." wut??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript is purely a way of helping the user. It's user friendliness, because before the user submits the data it is validated. 
Server-side validation should always be done, due to javascript possibly being disabled, so server-side validation is purely security and input proofing.

So you can keep javascript validation out of your application, however it does make using your application easier if you don't.

If you don't like javascript you can also use HTML5 validators, like using the "required" attribute: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/ , but just like javascript it does not ensure validation occurs, therefor server-side validation is always required!

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not enough. You should always validate your data on the server side, after the form has been submitted. Client-side validation and AJAX validation before submitting the form are only enhancing the user experience, by providing quicker feedback on invalid data. Both client-side validation and AJAX pre-submit validation do not and can not protect you from a maliciously crafted form submission. Attackers and abusers usually don't even use a browser in order to submit data to your server.

Answer (score 0):

The client side validation is to ease the user experience, give him some feedback, tooltips for inputs and so on. I always do server side and than I add ajax so the page doesn't reload and the user gets a quick feedback. If JS is turned off the server side will still work without touching the code again.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The main validations must be at the server code, before your database query. Also would be right validate at client side, so that the validation is faster and don't send a server request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is totally correct both side have there benefits:

Server Side Validation: Always must exist, the client side is easy to break, and you dont want have bad data in your DB.

Client Side Validation: Is optional, but is nice. Mainly use is for not receive unnecesary request from client to the server. The client love not make a request, and de serve not stress.

For Client Side Validation the best plugin is http://jqueryvalidation.org/ works fine the documentation is not full, but have a good community using.

For Server Side Validation, depends of framework you use Symfony 2, have form validation in the components